# Class 'HTML' not found with Laravel Collective Html

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I've replaced the `Illuminate\HTML` package with the Laravel Collective version and the composer stuff went fine but the ViewEngine still puts `HTML` instead of `Html` into my compiled views. I'm getting the following error

```
FatalErrorException in a59c8f4e39e21fe743ceaf7a4de9f1da line 14:
Class 'HTML' not found
```

This is the line it complains about

```
<?php echo HTML::style(elixir('css/backend.css')); ?>
```

My `config/app.php` looks like this

```
'Form'      => 'Collective\Html\FormFacade',
'Html'      => 'Collective\Html\HtmlFacade',
```

I'm using the Laravel 5 boilerplate from Rappasoft (https://github.com/rappasoft/laravel-5-boilerplate) and I have a feeling they used the `Illuminate` class somewhere but I can't find where. I've already edited `app/Providers/MacrosServiceProvider.php` and `app/services/Macro.php`.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the file required somewhere? E.g. `require_once '/path/to/file.php';`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Html::style(elixir('css/backend.css'))`, as that is how you define it in the config?

Comment: Also, try to avoid backslashes ('\') as these are escape strings, use  forward slashes ('/')

Comment: @SamSwift They're probably backslashes as they look like namespace'd classes.

Comment: @JonStirling Correct, that's basically the problem ; )

Comment: @SamSwift The package gets loaded automatically

Answer (score 0):

Silly mistake. Had to delete cached views in `storage/app/framework/views`